# what are the valid colors for mercurial's color extension?

Tags: colors, mercurial, ansi-term

Mercurial's `color` [extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ColorExtension) is great and all, but there isn't a list on that page of what the valid colors are. I looked for a python file named color, hoping I'd be able to read the source and see it there, but no luck. I was hoping to use grey or light grey for a color but it wasn't valid. Grey (or gray) seems like a pretty likely color to be in a list of colors.

Where can I find a list of valid colors for the `color` extension? Or where can I find the source for the `color` extension?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the source code at [Mercurial Color Extension](http://selenic.com/repo/hg-stable/file/436cc9d017c6/hgext/color.py).

By default, the colors it recognises are black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan, white.

But, as you'll see from the source, it's possible to define custom colours, but how you do this will depend on your terminal. Search for `brightblue` in the source.

Comment: Thanks. It's weird that I'm using color locally but I can't find color.py locally. I assumed all extensions were in py files. Apparently not.

Answer (score 3):

The valid - background and foreground - colors depend on the coloring mode mercurial is using. You get the most (?) flexibility when using terminfo coloring, in which case you typically have access to xterm's 256 color cube. [This python script](https://gist.github.com/mgedmin/2762225) by [Marius Gedminas](http://mailto:Marius%20Gedminas%20%3Cmarius@gedmin.as%3E) will list them all for you on your terminal (it's shell-executable starting with a shebang so you can just execute it directly - on a Unix'ish system). But to save you the trouble, I've linked to the output below.

Before listing all the colors, though, here's a concrete example of how to use that listing in your `.hgrc` file:

```
[extensions]
color =

[color]
mode=terminfo
color.lightgray = 250
color.darkgray = 239
status.modified = darkgray bold lightgray_background
```

This will produce dark gray text on a lighter gray background (these are not the 'canonical' dark and light gray colors though - those are 007 and 015). Note there's no separate definition for foreground vs background colors - you can just append `_background` to a defined color name.

[image: Color table]

Comment: Answering a 4 yr old question? Appreciate the effort -- you'll probably get a badge for it

Comment: @jcollum: I answered this because I just had the exact same issue and I had to figure out the specifics that were missing here before my answer. I do actually think mine should be the accepted one (linking to answers off-site without actually answering is frowned upon).

Comment: I think linking to the mercurial source code is fine in this case -- if that goes away well the question will be irrelevant

Comment: Note that `label('color.darkgray',...)` won't work in a template specification.  You need to use `label('darkgray',...)`.